# macOS Big Sur (11.1): How to summon "Unlocking with Apple Watch…" when Mac is locked but not raised from a sleep?

Tags: macos, keyboard, sleep-wake, password, unlock

When I wake my Mac from a sleep, I'm always able to unlock it with my linked Watch first. If it's unsuccessful due to any reasons, a prompt appears but in most situation everything works smoothly and I unlock without typing my password.

[image]

---

When I try to unlock my Mac just from the locked screen (not from a sleep) **I always get a prompt**.

The only way for me to unlock & log-in without typing password is to hit the `Esc` key on the lock screen to put it to sleep, hit any random key to wake it up and then I see "Unlocking with Apple Watch…".

Is there any keyboard shortcut to unlock on demand my Mac by a Watch on locked screen?

[image]